# Array of ranges no longer being set successfully after adding a range declaration on the same line

Tags: excel, vba

The code is falling down on the line `If snake(i).Column = 10 Then`
with the Runtime error 424, Object required. Upon checking for the existence of the range snake(i) where i = 3, there is none, but I cannot see why this range array and the other one that it relies on, box(), are not being set properly.

Context: As a personal challenge and to improve my understanding of VBA, I recreated a game of Snake from scratch in Excel. It was working perfectly fine until I started to add in some code, seen at the very bottom of the quote below, in order to add the occasional greater-value food items. I don't understand how code from further down can stop code further up from functioning how it used to. The only changes made to the code above the error line since the working version are the two variables applesEaten and gAppleCountdown which seem to me completely straightforward. Edit: I also added the declaration of the range goldenApple, which it turned out is the cause of the error.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws, scoreSheet As Worksheet
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
Set scoreSheet = wb.Worksheets(2)
Dim box(1 To 100) As Range
Dim vert, hori, i, step, re, rand, randResult, timeLoop, snakeHeadCol, snakeHeadRow, score, applesEaten, gAppleCountdown, speed, lastRow As Long
Dim snake(), goldenApple As Range
ReDim snake(1 To 3)
re = 3

speed = scoreSheet.Cells(2, 12).Value
applesEaten = 0
gAppleCountdown = 0
score = 0

For vert = 1 To 10
    For hori = 1 To 10
        Set box(hori + 10 * (vert - 1)) = ws.Cells(vert, hori)
    Next
Next

For i = 1 To 100
box(i) = ""
Next

Set snake(1) = box(44)
Set snake(2) = box(45)
Set snake(3) = box(46)

For i = LBound(snake) To UBound(snake)
snake(i) = 1
Next

box(49) = 2

step = 1

Do Until WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Range("A1:J10")) >= 101

i = UBound(snake)
Select Case direction
    Case 1
      If snake(i).Column = 10 Then

        If snake(i).Offset(0, -9) = 2 Or snake(i).Offset(0, -9) = 0.2 Then
            If snake(i).Offset(0, -9).Address = goldenApple.Address Then
            score = score + gAppleCountdown
            Set goldenApple = ws.Cells(11, 11)
            Else
            score = score + 1
            applesEaten = applesEaten + 1

            rand = Int((100 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
            randResult = rand
            Do While box(randResult) = 1
            rand = Int((100 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
            randResult = rand
            Loop
            box(randResult) = 2

            End If

            re = re + 1
            ReDim Preserve snake(1 To re)
            Set snake(re) = snake(re - 1).Offset(0, -9)
            snake(re) = 1

                If applesEaten Mod 5 = 0 Then
                rand = Int((100 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
                randResult = rand
                Do While box(randResult) = 1
                rand = Int((100 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
                randResult = rand
                Loop
                Set goldenApple = box(randResult)
                goldenApple = 0.2
                gAppleCountdown = 5
                ws.Cells(1, 11) = gAppleCountdown
                Else
                End If

            ws.Cells(23, 5) = score
```

Comment: Snake is an `Array` not a `Range` so it has no `.Column` property. `Dim snake(), goldenApple As Range` means snake() is an array and goldenApple a Range.

Comment: But it's falling down on snake(i).column, and snake(i) is a single-cell range, rather than the entire array.

Comment: Again, your `snake` is an array, you can't use `.Column` you need to set a range first using the `snake(i)`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling to understand. Could you show me what you mean in practice, by adapting the code above?

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it by declaring the array of ranges and the single range separately: `Dim snake() As Range` on one line and then on the next line `Dim goldenApple As Range`. Do you (or anybody else) know why this results in different behaviour (no error)? I guess it's because before it was seeing it as `Dim snake()` without the `as Range` part.

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to Damian, for explaining in the comments, the problem was the line

```
Dim snake(), goldenApple As Range
```

This is equivalent to

```
Dim snake()
Dim goldenApple As Range
```

when what is really required is

```
Dim snake() As Range, Dim goldenApple As Range
```

or

```
Dim snake() As Range
Dim goldenApple As Range
```

Declarations of type `Dim snake()` by default provide for variants.

Comment: Side note: (array) declarations without explicit type indication (e.g. `Dim snake()` provide for **variants**, not for *strings*.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense.